# Create NumPy array from another array by specifying rows and columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I create a NumPy array `B` which is a sub-array of a NumPy array `A`, by specifying which rows and columns (indicated by `x` and `y` respectively) are to be included?

For example:

```
A = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
x = [0, 2]
y = [1, 3, 4]
B = # Do something .....
```

Should give the output:

```
>>> B
array([[2, 4, 5], [12, 14, 15]])
```

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do this is to use the `ix_` function: see the [answer by MSeifert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46045439/3923281) for details.

Alternatively, you could use chain the indexing operations using `x` and `y`:

```
>>> A[x][:,y]
array([[ 2,  4,  5],
       [12, 14, 15]])
```

First `x` is used to select the rows of `A`. Next, `[:,y]` picks out the columns of the subarray specified by the elements of `y`.

The chaining is symmetric in this case: you can also choose the columns first with `A[:,y][x]` if you wish.

Comment: Note that this is not a new array, but a view of the original one, using the same data in memory.

Comment: This is actually a new array - fancy indexing (i.e using an array of values, rather than a single value or slice) triggers copying.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) which allows to broadcast the integer index arrays:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
>>> x = [0, 2]
>>> y = [1, 3, 4]
>>> A[np.ix_(x, y)]
array([[ 2,  4,  5],
       [12, 14, 15]])
```

From the documentation the `ix_` function was designed so

> [...] one can quickly construct index arrays that will index the cross product. `a[np.ix_([1,3],[2,5])]` returns the array `[[a[1,2] a[1,5]], [a[3,2] a[3,5]]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a super verbose way to get what you want:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
x = [0, 2]
y = [1,3,4]

a2 = a.tolist()
a3 = [[l for k,l in enumerate(j) if k in y] for i,j in enumerate(a2) if i in x]
b = np.array(a3)
```

But please follow @ajcr answer:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
x = [0, 2]
y = [1,3,4]
a[x][:,y]
```