# Rearranging rows and columns of a numpy array (in a single operation)

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

First let's put that out of the way:
I'm already aware of the solution discussed here: [Create NumPy array from another array by specifying rows and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493689/create-numpy-array-from-another-array-by-specifying-rows-and-columns)

Let's say I have an array

```
test = np.arange(12).reshape((3,4))

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

and I want to rearrange its rows and columns into `test2`

```
array([[ 1,  0,  3,  2],
       [ 9,  8, 11, 10],
       [ 5,  4,  7,  6]])
```

The solution I'm using right now is the same as the one already answered in the link above:

```
test2 = test[[0,2,1]][:,[1,0,3,2]]
```

However this solution creates an unnecessary intermediate copy of the data: it first creates a copy with shuffled rows only `test[[0,2,1]]`, then creates a second copy with shuffled columns as well. For such a small array, no one cares but if the array is gigantic this solution feels sub-optimal. Does numpy allow rows and columns shuffling simultaneously? Something looking like `test[[0,2,1],[1,0,3,2]]`, except numpy doesn't interpret this operation that way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's the purpose of [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html):

```
>>> test[np.ix_([0,2,1], [1,0,3,2])]
array([[ 1,  0,  3,  2],
       [ 9,  8, 11, 10],
       [ 5,  4,  7,  6]])
```

It will still create an intermediate index array from the two input arrays but it won't index the `test` array twice.

Note that `np.ix_` just adds dimensions to your index arrays, these will be "broadcasted" when you index the array:

```
>>> np.ix_([0,2,1], [1,0,3,2])
(array([[0],
        [2],
        [1]]), array([[1, 0, 3, 2]]))
```

Comment: This solution seems twice slower than my current one...

Comment: Actually it's (only) marginally faster when tested on bigger arrays.

Comment: Yes, the break even seems to be high. However with 1kk items it's already significantly faster (2 times on my computer).

Comment: Well I was hoping for better, but apparently that's as good as numpy allows...

Comment: It made a **huuuuge** difference reordering a `70k x 70k` boolean array `a`: **209.20s** and **35.14s** for `a[idxs][:, idxs]` and `a[np.ix_(idxs, idxs)` respectively